# VS Code Error: command 'extension.executeAREPLBlock' not found (Using Mac)

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I use to be able to use the "cmd + enter" to skip down to the next line of code even if the curser was in the middle of the line somewhere.

When I make use of that key combination, I am prompted with `command 'extension.executeAREPLBlock' not found` error.

I did see a couple other articles on Stack Overflow but they were far more complex than what I have going on.

Can someone please help resolve this for me? It would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my settings.json if it helps.

```
{
"editor.suggestSelection": "first",
"vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
"files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
"workbench.iconTheme": "eq-material-theme-icons",
"files.associations": {
    "*.py": "python"
},
"[python]": {
    "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
},
"vsintellicode.modelDownloadPath": "",
"editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
"code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
"terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows": "",
"editor.fontLigatures": true,
"editor.fontFamily": "Cascadia Code, Menlo, Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace",
"editor.fontSize": 16,}
```

Comment: Sorry about this. I created a bug report, follow https://github.com/Almenon/AREPL-vscode/issues/447 for updates.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the "AREPL for Python" extension may be causing a conflict with "cmd + enter" shortcut, since that extension uses that same key combination.

To restore "cmd + enter" to its prior functionality, open your keyboard shortcuts ("cmd + shft + p") and search for "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts".

Click on "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts" and then in the search bar type the following (**include the quotes**): "cmd + enter". You should see a couple options including "AREPL: execute the current block of code".

Click on the pencil icon to the left of this option and enter a new keyboard shortcut that is not "cmd+enter".  For example, maybe type this key combination (type the actual keys, don't type the key abbreviations as I have here): cmd + ctrl + enter.  Then hit enter.

Now that you gave the AREPL a different keyboard shortcut, hopefully the previous functionality of "cmd + enter" will be restored.

Comment: this does not work.

Comment: Just tested this and can confirm it works. @D.L I would try doing it again. To verify that you have done it correctly you can search for "cmd + enter" to make sure the arepl keybinding is no longer present.

Answer (score 0):

"AREPL for Python" extension was causing the conflict for me.

I simply uninstalled the extension and it works are normal.